# Django Tests run faster with no internet connection

Tags: python, django, testing, python-unittest

I have a django test suite that builds a DB from a 400 line fixture file. It runs unfortunately slow. Several seconds per test.

I was on the train yesterday developing without internet access, with my wifi turned off, and I noticed my tests ran literally 10x faster without internet. And they are definitely running correctly.

Everything is local, it all runs fine without an internet connection. The tests themselves do not hit any APIs or make any other connections, so it seems it must be something else.

Comment: Im experiencing the same problem. How did you solve this?

Comment: My problem was due to the localhost alias `local.dev`. Its doing DNS queries to check TLD `.dev`. I removed the dot and problem solved.

Comment: Thanks noel! My problem was similar, but was on local server. I need a custom domain on localhost. Editing hosts file isn't enough. Had to change DNS settings to use localhost as the top DNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This most likely means you've got some component installed which is trying to make network connections. Possibly something that does monitoring or statistics gathering?

The simplest way to figure out what's going on is to use tcpdump to capture your network traffic and see what's going on. To do that:

1. Run `tcpdump -i any` (or `tcpdump -i en1` if you're on a mac; the airport is usually `en1`, but you can double check with `ifconfig`)
2. Watch the traffic to get some idea what's normal
3. Run your test suite
4. Watch the traffic printed by `tcpdump` to see if anything obviously jumps out at you

Comment: Does this mean anything to you? It runs like that seemingly for each test: https://gist.github.com/shaneharter/4283d7a7aa5768d812eb

Comment: Looks like you're either sending content to, or getting content from, a content delivery network. I don't know off the top of my head what would be doing that, but possibly something to do with static file handling? Unfortunately it's HTTPS, so digging further would be difficult unless you've got something like Charles Proxy installed.