# Pytest tests are very slow without internet though no test makes network calls

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

I am having a weird issue with pytest in a Django project.

When I run a **single empty unit test**,

> It takes on average 7 secs, with reuse db, takes 3 secs on avg.
>
> With wifi off, it takes 20 secs on avg.
>
> With wifi on and network disabled, takes >150 secs on avg.

For other team members of mine, there is no difference in time for the above mentioned cases. I checked using different network monitoring tools and there is no network activity happening also.

Comment: Interesting...see this (not a solution, but the opposite problem): http://stackoverflow.com/q/28864152/3642398